# Extracting multiple digits from pandas non-uniform column with classification

Tags: python, regex, pandas

df with a text column 'DescCol' that has been entered variously with no consistent but, somewhat similar patterns. I need to:

- (a) extract all substrings within parentheses
- (b) if the extracted substring contains numbers then:
- (b.i) if (b) the beginning text is in ('Up to', '<', 'Tolerance') - so mark a boolean column 'isToleranceSpec' Yes for 'Tolerance', No otherwise
- (b.ii) extract the digit following the beginning text of the substring (which may or may not have comma separator) into a column called 'BandLimit'
- (b.iii) then check if there is further follow-on text ('thereafter' AFAIK)
- (b.iv) if (b.iii) then extract the number following 'thereafter' into a column called 'Marginal' else continue
- (c) if not (b): continue

So the result df will look like below ('Remarks' columns highlights some of the peculiarities I've noticed in the data so far):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DescCol":["beginning text (Up to 1,234 days, thereafter 11d each) ending text", 
                            "beginning text (Up to 1234 days, thereafter 11d each) ending text",
                            "beginning text (Tolerance 4,567 days, thereafter 12d each) ending text",
                            "beginning text (Tolerance 4567 days, thereafter 12d each) ending text", 
                            "beginning text (Tolerance 891011 days) ending text",
                            "beginning text (<1,112 days, thereafter 13d each) ending text", 
                             "beginning text (no numbers within parentheses) ending text"],
                 "Remarks": ["comma in number",
                                "no comma in number",
                                "tolerance with thereafter, comma in large number",
                                "tolerance with thereafter, no comma in large number",
                                "tolerance without thereafter",
                                "less than sign used + comma in number", 
                                "non-relevant row"],
                 "isToleranceSpec": ["No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", ''],
                 "BandLimit": [1234, 1234, 4567, 4567, 891011, 1112, ''],
                 "Marginal": [11, 11, 12, 12, '', 13, '']})
```

I can uppercase DescCol and extract the sub-string b/w '(' and ')', any pithy solutions post that v welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, but here is a pity solution:

```
def extract_infos(row):
    # check numbers in parentheses
    m = re.findall('\(.*\d.*\)', row.DescCol) 
    if len(m) != 1:
        return
    t = m[0][1:-1] # strip the ()
    # tolerance and bandlimit
    row['isToleranceSpec'] = 'Yes' if any(t.startswith(x) for x in  ('Up to', '<', 'Tolerance')) else 'No'
    row['BandLimit'] = int(re.findall('\d+,?\d*', t)[0].replace(',', ''))
    # marginal
    m = re.search('thereafter (\d+)', t)
    if m is not None:
        row['Marginal'] = int(m.groups()[0])
    return row
```

This method can then be used like this:

```
# start with a DataFrame that has only DescCol
start = your_example_df[['DescCol']].copy()
# add default column values
for c in ['isToleranceSpec', 'BandLimit', 'Marginal']:
    start[c] = '' # weird to have empty strings in int columns, but...

# Do the magic !
_ = start.apply(extract_infos, axis=1)
```

It does work for your example, but you might want to add some additional checks (e.g.: I suppose that if there is a `thereafter`, there is necessarily a number after, etc.)

Comment: 'weird to have empty strings in int columns, but...' I do it as well to speed up the code - it just pre-allocates memory beforehand across the start df, the program will still run w/o that but v slow. Thanks for the reply btw, spot on!

Comment: you could initialize at 0, would be better so that the dtype is int, not object. Happy to help